# Action of semidirect products of cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-actions

Is there anything known about group actions of $C_{p}\rtimes C_{p}^{*}$ on the ring of real polynomials $\mathbb{R}[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}]$, where $C_{p}$ denotes the cyclic group of order $p$ and $p$ is prime? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: What do you want to know about these group actions? Please try to find a more focused question

Comment: $C_p^*$ is particularly awkward because it makes use of a choice of field structure on $C_p$ (which is determined only after the choice of some generator devoted to be the multiplicative unit)

Comment: I think the most natural action of the group you say is permutations of a set with $p$ elements (it's the "affine general linear group" AGL(1,$p$)).  This action is easy to understand.  So the group could permute $p$ of the variables in a nice way...